# Share Intent with Facebook and other social app

Tags: facebook, share, whatsapp

I want to share a text and link to users if an Android app. If the user selects Faebook, it should share only a link (as Facebook only accepts links from native Android share), if user selects other apps like whatsapp,soma  it should share text. How can I implement this?

Comment: It would be helpful to explain what solutions you have already looked at. Or, if you have any code, to post some snippets that highlight where you are having problems.

Comment: Hi , please help me to solve Android share content intent problem I want to share a Text and link to users like if user select Facebook should share only link(as facebook only accept link from native android share), if user select other app like whatsapp,soma should share TEXT. how can I implement this. please help me. thanks a lot.